# Grails 2.4 JDBC SpringSecurity RC4

Tags: tomcat, grails, spring-security, spring-jdbc

Upgraded to Grails 2.4.3 from 2.1 we seem to have an issue with JDBC connections to MySQL DB timing out? I've followed a few online guides but struggling.

in my datasource I have:

```
test {
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://MYURL"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
        properties {
            // Documentation for Tomcat JDBC Pool
            // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes
            // https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html
            jmxEnabled = true
            initialSize = 5
            maxActive = 50
            minIdle = 5
            maxIdle = 25
            maxWait = 10000
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            validationInterval = 15000
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = false
            ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad = true
            // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
            defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED // safe default
            // controls for leaked connections
            abandonWhenPercentageFull = 100 // settings are active only when pool is full
            removeAbandonedTimeout = 120
            removeAbandoned = true
            // use JMX console to change this setting at runtime
            logAbandoned = false // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging
            // JDBC driver properties
            // Mysql as example
            dbProperties {
                // Mysql specific driver properties
                // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
                // let Tomcat JDBC Pool handle reconnecting
                autoReconnect = false
                // truncation behaviour
                jdbcCompliantTruncation = false
                // mysql 0-date conversion
                zeroDateTimeBehavior = 'convertToNull'
                // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementCache is used instead, so disable mysql driver's cache
                cachePrepStmts = false
                cacheCallableStmts = false
                // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementFinalizer keeps track
                dontTrackOpenResources = true
                // performance optimization: reduce number of SQLExceptions thrown in mysql driver code
                holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose = true
                // enable MySQL query cache - using server prep stmts will disable query caching
                useServerPrepStmts = false
                // metadata caching
                cacheServerConfiguration = true
                cacheResultSetMetadata = true
                metadataCacheSize = 100
                // timeouts for TCP/IP
                connectTimeout = 15000
                socketTimeout = 120000
                // timer tuning (disable)
                maintainTimeStats = false
                enableQueryTimeouts = false
                // misc tuning
                noDatetimeStringSync = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the SpringSecurity Core Plugin and the Spring Security UI... After the user has logged in and then timesout I get an error telling the user that their account has expired. Before I added the dbProperties configs suggested in the Grails documentation I would get the following JDBC error:

> [http-8080-6] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
>
> [http-8080-6] ERROR transaction.JDBCTransaction  - Could not toggle autocommit
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
>
> Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.. Stacktrace follows:
>   java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

Comment: There's a lot going on here. Try to reduce the number of variables so you can focus on one issue at a time, especially when they're unrelated. It's very unlikely that connectivity issues have anything to do with reporting that an user account has expired. If that's incorrect, isolate it from the database issue and figure out what's up. Separately, get the database connectivity fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Burt... After a bit more investigation the Password Expired issue looks like odd behaviour to me... not sure if it's something you've missed?

If a user has the Password Expired flag set to true then they can reset their password. The user then goes through the process of putting in their username and getting the reset password link sent via email. Following this link and entering a new password the user is then logged into the system HOWEVER the password expired flag never gets set to true... after the account is logged out or timesout the user can't get back in until resetting their password again. so either there is a flaw in that the user can remain within the system after resetting their password OR the flag should be set upon successful password change so the user isn't forced to continually reset or speak to an admin?

The JDBC error is working correctly with the above code but I agree that not all variables are required.